# Change the display format of number field in Maximo

Tags: maximo

After adding a number field using the database configuration of Maximo and applying the changes, I quickly added the new field to the application using the Application designer.

To my surprise when I enter the number, it is displayed with comma separators (which I don't want).

i.e. 1000456 is entered and 1,000,456 is displayed.

How can I make Maximo display this as is, without the comma's to separate.

**Update**:

I have already searched for display option in the application designer and in the database configuration application, but I don't see anything about display options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has to do with your localization settings. And the number is going to be stored without the commas. But if you're wanting the display to not have commas, I think the best way to get what you want is with an ALN-type attribute and an autoscript that does a regular expression match on the ALN to check for just digits being entered.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (to change it to ALN), but thinking it through I realize I won't be doing calculations with the number, so changing to ALN solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same problem and this is the script I made in Python, it basically removes the characters from the string, I'm happy to help if anybody needs it:

```
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
onlynumbers= ''
word = mbo.getString("DESCRIPTION")

for c in word:
    if c in numbers:
        onlynumbers = onlynumbers + c

mbo.setValue("DESCRIPTION",onlynumbers)
```

Comment: what is `mbo`? Also, consider wrapping your code in a function and/or produce a minimal working solution / example.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this was a script with a validation action point, mbo is the way to reference the object itself, in Java this would be "this"